# Merging of fields using xml path in sql server, display comma where NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in which two or more different dates are listed for a single id. I want to merge all the dates for a single id. Example code is as below.

```
create table number(id nvarchar(255), billdate nvarchar(255))
insert into number(id,billdate) values ('56465','12/10/2011'),('56465','02/11/2011'),   
('46462','12/09/2009'),('46462','12/06/2010'),('32169','12/22/2009'),
('32169','12/31/2011'),('86835','12/10/2010'),('86835','22-Jan-2010'),
('65641',''),('65641','12-Aug-2009'),('22458','25-Aug-2007'),('22458','')
```

For merging the rows I am using xml path as below

```
select Main.id,LEFT(Main.billdate,nullif(LEN(Main.billdate)-1,-1)) as "billdate"
from (select distinct ST2.id,(SELECT ST1.billdate + ',' AS [text()]
from NUMBER ST1 where ST1.id=ST2.id ORDER BY ST1.id FOR XML PATH (''))billdate
from NUMBER ST2)[Main]
```

It is working perfectly for this sample data, But the Problem is I have huge data, and when I apply this XML path code a comma is not displayed if a date is NULL, like for the id 65641. Its important for me to display a comma in the place of NULL. Where am I going wrong? Can anyone suggest why it's not displaying a comma in the place of NULL?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I perfectly understand you, since the putatively NULL value for 65641 is actually a blank.  To treat NULL values like blanks, you can use this:

```
select Main.id,LEFT(Main.billdate,nullif(LEN(Main.billdate)-1,-1)) as "billdate"
from 
(
    select distinct ST2.id,
    (
        SELECT ISNULL(ST1.billdate + ',', ',') AS [text()]
        from NUMBER ST1 
        where ST1.id=ST2.id 
        ORDER BY ST1.id 
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) billdate
    from NUMBER ST2
)[Main]
```

The other issue you might be having is that if there is only a single blank/NULL value for a given `id`, you don't get even a single comma for it.  This is happening because a single blank value only generates a single comma, which is then stripped off by your `LEFT` statement.  You can make it leave single commas alone by changing it like so:

```
select Main.id,LEFT(Main.billdate,nullif(LEN(Main.billdate)-CASE WHEN LEN(Main.billdate) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,-1)) as "billdate"
from 
(
    select distinct ST2.id,
    (
        SELECT ISNULL(ST1.billdate + ',', ',') AS [text()]
        from NUMBER ST1 
        where ST1.id=ST2.id 
        ORDER BY ST1.id 
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) billdate
    from NUMBER ST2
)[Main]
```

You still have issues, one of which is that you have no explicit ordering of dates, but I hope that covers the problems that you have.  If not, clarify and I'll attempt to help some more.